# Can I use a starter check to open a bank account?

Tags: banking

Someone wrote me a personal check using a starter check. Can I use it to open a bank account, or cash it at their bank?

Comment: Go to the bank and try?

Comment: You should definitely be able to cash it at the issuing bank. They should also let you use it to open an account there. Don't know how other banks would treat it though.

Comment: If "starter checks" weren't acceptable, why would the banks hand them out with new accounts?

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I can foresee with opening an account with the check is that it does not have the name of the person who wrote you the check at the top. Other than that, it is a legitimate check. As you would most likely be opening the account in person and the check is hopefully valid, then you should not have an issue using the check.

If the bank *does* refuse to use the check, then you should either have the person who wrote it reissue it with a normal personal check/money order or go to the bank that they use and have them cash it and then take it to the bank that you would be opening an account with and use the cash to open an account.